# UK reg business (not vat reg) paying consultancy fee to the EU consultant (not vat reg)

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, accounting

My limited company is registered in England (not vat registered though). I need to make a payment to a consultant abroad in the EU who is not vat registered.

Do I need to pay anything to the HMRC and will the payment to the consultant be considered a business expense and thus reduce the amount of corporate tax to be paid at the end of the tax year?

Do I need to collect any documents or provide information to anyone at this point (other than keeping the records: invoice, transactions etc.)?

Much obliged for your advice. Thank you

Comment: Since you run a business, you likely will have an accountant. If not, I am not sure it's wise to rely on somebody's anonymous comments on the internet for such matters.

Comment: Unless you have private customers who would have to pay VAT out of their own pocket, you should register for the VAT flat rate scheme which will give you some free money. About 3% of your revenue.

Comment: @AKdemy who says I will blindly rely on the advice given to me on this website? This is your shallow assumption. This website is created to support other people's questions, is it not? Moreover, whether the person acts on the advice provided here is non of your business. If you have nothing concrete to support this discussion, you should refrain from posting - it doesn't earn you any points kid.

Comment: @West, it was a genuine advice that I think its best to ask an accountant who is trained and qualified to answer such questions. After all, personal finance and money isn't about business related questions although small businesses are somewhat OK I suppose. There is no need to be upset if you disagree with someone's opinion. If you feel offended everytime somebody posts a comment or answer that doesn't suit you, you might need to rethink if asking questions online is really the best choice for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Payment to that consultant will be a business expense (assuming the consultant charges for work for your business). So it reduces your profit and corporation tax.

Not being VAT registered means you pay their bill, whether it contains VAT or not. Lookup “VAT flat rate scheme” which will likely be beneficial for you.

Comment: So, if I do not pay vat and I'm not registered with vat, and the consultant in the EU is not registered for the vat either, I do not have to pay anything except the agreed £2k (on the invoice)? PS. Their bill doesn't contain VAT and I'm not bothered about getting some VAT back for myself at this point hence I'm not much into registering for VAT at this point in time (but I appreciate you pointing this out - thx).

Comment: Not registering for flat rate VAT is throwing away money. Made me £3,000 the last tax year with zero effort. But you don't have to obviously.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you need an invoice. The invoice should have all the required details, including both companies names and addresses, the description of the services provided, the cost, etc. Most likely it should have a registration number of the company which issued it. It needs to have a number and a date.

In most cases such expenses can indeed be taken into account into… your companies expenses, so when you file your accounts and your CT return it will be on expenses, and it will reduce the CT you owe.

The rules for when you can expense things are complex, but essentially if it’s something which is actually for the business it should be OK. Rules for VAT are more complex but since none is involved here the question does not arise.